# Why is there no .o after compiling?

Tags: c++, makefile, compilation

After each change of my code, I have to compile the whole program because the .o files are not saved, what's wrong with the makefile?

```
CXX=g++
CXXFLAGS=-W -Wall -ansi -pedantic
LDFLAGS=
EXEC=test

SRC= $(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJ= $(SRC:.c=.o)

all: $(EXEC)
    @echo "$(CYAN)\n\tProgram successfully compiled!\n\a$(BLACK)"

$(EXEC): $(OBJ)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) -o $@ -c $< $(CXXFLAGS)
```

Comment: This looks wrong `OBJ= $(SRC:.c=.o)`, should be `OBJ= $(SRC:.cpp=.o)`

Comment: Not related: for sorted-compile-order, try  SRC=$(sort $(wildcard *.cc))

Comment: Yet another point: `%.o: %.cpp` rule is (almost) the same as a built-in one. So, unless you're used to type `make -r` or always add `.SUFFIXES:` to your makefiles, it could be safely omitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks John to figure it out!

The problem is this line:

OBJ= $(SRC:.c=.o)

It has to be like this:

OBJ= $(SRC:.cpp=.o)

indeed, I copied the structure from a makefile to compile C programs, so I have to modify the extension of the source files!